# Deleting a global structure through a local variable

Tags: python

I came across [some code](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/blob/c0c7d6c6c724fb295845c0583d0c7b3de870e0d5/shapely/geos.py#L794) that seems to do this:

```
def cleanup(x):
    del x

atexit.register(cleanup, some_global_structure)
```

Does this actually *do* anything? I would expect the `del` statement to just delete the local variable, having no effect whatsoever on the global structure.

(Hm, I just noticed that someone [commented](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/commit/7628b3909422afbc39b2bdc41bd76599cafe0a28#r31586174) on the pull request that introduced this... Maybe it's just a mistake.)

Comment: If anything, it's likely creating an extra reference to `some_global_structure`, for the call by `atexit`, ensuring the object will stick around until the function is called, even if other references are cleaned up in the meantime. I'm not sure the `del` is even needed at that point, but that may just be a matter of documenting the function's code with that statement

Comment: @Grismar Ah, so it's not really a clean-up, but a keep-alive!

Comment: Before that pull request that you found, the `cleanup()` function would `del` a global variable, which actually would have an effect. The current version looks like a mistake.

Comment: @khelwood Yes, that makes sense.

Comment: @TurePålsson - correct, it might be put there to avoid having to reinitialise the structure for later use. I haven't looked in detail at the rest of the code, that might provide some insight as to why the author would want that to happen. It does make sense that the reference is passed to `atexit`, from that point of view.